# Django Framework: wrong confirmation email

Tags: python, django, passwords

So guys this is what I have in my reset_password_email.html file:

```
> {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'accounts:reset_password_confirm'uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

This is my urls.py file:

```
url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', password_reset_confirm, {'template_name': 'accounts/reset_password_confirm.html', 'post_reset_redirect': '/account/reset-password/complete/'}, name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

And this is the E-Mail-Link that I reveive and doesn't work(example):

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/reset-password/confirm/Mg/4r7-e49456caf2260a8ed103/

If I change the link to account instead of accounts (see below), it works:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/reset-password/confirm/Mg/4r7-e49456caf2260a8ed103/

Comment: I have most of an answer, but is there a top level urls.py where you're importing your auth/accounts module urls? That `urls.py` supplied doesn't account for the first part of the namespace, and I want to check something before I answer.

Comment: show us all of your urls.py, including the one that includes this one.

Comment: Thank you guys; I found it. In my other urls.py the namespace for account was accounts instead of account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong namespace in my other urls.py

It was:

```
url(r'^account/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='account**s**'))
```

Instead of:

```
url(r'^account/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='account'))
```